# Transformer winding voltages shouldn't add in additive polarity?

Tags: transformer, ac-polarity

In the figure at right, I believe the terminals are at the following potentials:

- H1 = 0V
- H2 = 120V
- X1 = 0V
- X2 = 30V

Doesn't it follow that the potential difference across H2 and X1 is 120V (not 150V)?

[image]

[Source](https://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/electrical_engineering/Transformer_Polarity.pdf)

Comment: You describe an autotransformer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer for info.

Comment: How can you say H1=0V and X2=30V when H1 and X2 are connected to each other with a wire?

Comment: @user253751 Well, strictly speaking all points are connected to each other with a wire...  I am being facetious, of course, but also a burnt child.  Audio and RF engineering cannot depend on non-conservative electric fields confining themselves to inside "devices".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make things clearer, draw out a schematic diagram. The diagrams posted are hard to comprehend at a quick glance. The dots on the transformer windings show the phase of the windings with respect to each other.

[image: schematic]

In A, V[X2:H2] = 90 V.

In B, V[X1:H2] = 150 V. The drawing in B is drawn to confuse the reader, but the important thing is the turn direction in A & B are the same. 
If V[X1:H2] = 120, that would mean the X1:X2 winding would be zero volts which is clearly not the case. Can you explain how you got 120 V?

Answer (score 3):

Transformers A and B are identical despite the slightly different drawings. Looking down from the top both windings start at 1 (X1 and H1) and are wound anti-clockwise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZpDKI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

- In Figure 1a the windings are in-phase so the voltage between the output terminals is the **difference** between them.
- In Figure 1b the windings are wired out of phase. (CircuitLab doesn't permit me to move the dot on the secondary so it is incorrect.) Now X1 is 180° out of phase so the voltages are **additive**. While H2 is going up, X1 is going down and vice versa.